# Gnuplot plot a 2D heatmap in polar coordinates from Matrix data

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap, polar-coordinates

the past days I tried to plot a matrix into a polar 2D heatmap. The matrix consists of 80x720 data points. To specify the whole thing a bit more. It is data from a XRD in polar coordinates (a pole figure). The columns are the angular the sample was rotated around between 0° and 360° in steps of 0.5° (lets call it *phi*), the rows are another angular the sample was tilted by between 35° and 75° in 0.5° steps (lets call this one *psi*). The value on a specific position in the matrix is the intensity from the detector at these angulars. I want to end up with a polar plot where the radius is *psi*, the angular is *phi* and z or more precise the color represents the intensity.

I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792461/gnuplot-2d-polar-plot-with-heatmap-from-3d-dataset-possible) nicely discussed question but could not apply it to my problem. I managed to plot the whole thing with **splot** -file- **matrix u ($2/2):($1/2):3**  using a pm3d map but thats obviously not polar.

Does anyone here has an idea how to plot the matrix in polar form?
Thanks very much! Any advice about what direction to take would be very much appreciated

(I also have 80 individual data files of this measurement with the psi angular (0°-360°) and the corresponding intensity which didn't help me much so far).

cheers
Flo

Comment: I'm not aware of a direct gnuplot polar heatmap plotting style, but you could check this as a starting point... https://stackoverflow.com/a/62447578/7295599  This needs to be adapted to your specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please see `help set mapping` for an explanation of the coordinate transform produced by `set mapping cylindrical`.   If I understand correctly, you may be able to use something like:

```
set mapping cylindrical
set view equal xy
set view map
set angle degrees
splot 'data' matrix using 2:1:3 with pm3d
```

If the numerical values in the file are not already angular values, you may need conversion functions, e.g. from sample number to the corresponding angle:

```
theta(col) = col * 0.5
phi(row) = some_offset + row * some_scale_factor
splot 'data' matrix using (theta($2)) : (phi($1)) : 3 with pm3d
```

If that comes out badly, please attach an actual data file so that we can sort out what additional data specification might be necessary.  I show below an example using artificial data in the form of a linear gradient.  The urange and vrange are only relevant to define the sampling grid for the artificial data `'++'` ; you don't need them for data from a file.

```
set cblabel "Intensity"
unset border
set tics nomirror
set xtics axis; set ytics axis
set xzeroaxis; set yzeroaxis
set vrange [25:290]    # This is the column number (theta in 0.5° steps)
set urange [10:20]     # This is the row number (phi)

splot '++' using (theta($2)) : 1 : ($1) with pm3d notitle
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! It is working now. I have used the mapping command before but it did not work. I played around with it a while and permutated the argument in "splot using" a bit and now it is working. I don't know why but I had to change it to 2:3:1 now. Thank you so much! I was going crazy with this plot.

Comment: Is there by any chance an easy way of aligning the splot with the polar "empty" plot without shifting and scaling a lot?

Comment: No, but you could use `set xtics axis; set ytics axis; set xzeroaxis; set yzeroaxis` to reposition the x and y labels to the center of the plot.

Answer (score 0):

**Revisiting from the future**

Gnuplot version 6 offers a polar heatmap plotting style via the new command `set polar grid`.  It is analogous to the Cartesian coordinate mode controlled by `set dgrid3d`.

```
#
# Polar mode heat map in gnuplot version 6
# artificially generated data points
#

set cblabel "Intensity"
unset key
set palette cubehelix negative

set isotropic   # make the circle look circular

set polar
set angle degrees


# Define a grid with 0.5° increments on theta; 1 unit increments on r.
# Contributions from nearby grid points will be summed.
set polar grid 720, 50  qnorm 1 kdensity scale 0.001

set rrange [0:50]

set tics front
unset xtics
unset ytics
set rtics 10.0
set ttics 0,30,330 format "%h°"
set border 0 polar
set grid front polar

# The data source '++' will sample the two variables u and v.
# We use u to generate 200 theta values from 25° to 290°
# We use v to generate 11 r values 10,11,12,...20  (explicit sampling interval)
# The point at (theta,r) is assigned randomized value f(r) just to have some variety.

f(r) = rand(0)

set samples 200
plot sample [u=25:290][v=10:20:1] '++' using 1:2:(f($2)) with surface
```

[image]